# Casting JSON data in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm getting some JSON data from a server that I've parsed to a dictionary. Now I want to get the data from the dictionary and cast it as different types but I get some errors.

I've tried

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.GET(
    "http://localhost/example/jsonpage",
    parameters: nil,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
        responseObject: AnyObject!) in

        if let data = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let id = data["id"] as? Int
            let persons = data["persons"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        }


    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
        error: NSError!) in
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
)
```

These gives me an error:

```
let id = data["id"] as? Int
let persons = data["persons"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Error:
`Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Comment: can you show us how you're parsing the JSON?

Comment: Updated the question with more of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `responseObject` is of Type `NSDictionary`, and the supported JSON value Types are NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber. Casting to Dictionary does not cast its values to the correct Type. You have to cast the values individually.

```
if let nsid: NSNumber = data["id"] as? NSNumber {
    var id = Int(nsid)
}
```

Comment: Gives an error saying `fatal error: value failed to bridge from Objective-C type to a Swift type` at `if let nsid = data["id"] as? NSNumber {`

Comment: @Oskar I made the correction above. Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an intermediate cast to NSNumber or NSDictionary respectively resolves the error and achieves exactly the cast you want:

```
let id = data["id"] as? NSNumber as? Int
let persons = data["persons"] as? NSDictionary as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score -1):

You typed `responseObject` as `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` — meaning this dictionary can only contain *objects* as values; but an `Int` is not an object but a struct.

Therefore, you only need to rewrite your code using `Any` instead (`Any` is a class representing any object or struct):

```
if let data = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
    let id = data["id"] as? Int
    let persons = data["persons"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying `fatal error: value failed to bridge from Objective-C type to a Swift type` at `let id...` and `let persons...`

Comment: Argh, should have run it. iOS JSON uses NSNumbers for ints, etc. My bad.